# Thomas Kahn's Smooth Div Scroll - Hotspots Behaviour

Tags: html, scroll, smoothing

I am using Thomas Kahn's smooth div scroll for "mixed content". Basically I have an issue when scrolling left or right using the hotspots. I have 6 "contentbox" in my HTML. This can obviously go up and down depending on whether content expires or new content is published. Let me explain the scenario to you. The first time the page is loaded, I have the 6 "contentbox" coming up in the descending order of the date. Now once the scroliing begins, let us say 2 "contentbox" scrolled out of the screen from the left side. At this stage, if I scroll left using the left hotspot, it goes back only one. What I want is that it should go back upto the first "contentbox" I have on my HTML. Similarly, if I scroll right, it should go upto the last "contentbox" I have on my HTML. Is this possible?

FYI, when we disable "auto scrolling", the left and the right hotspot work as expected. However, our requirement is to scroll at the same time the left and the right hotspot should traverse to the first and last "contentbox" respectively.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Link to DropBox --->> https://www.dropbox.com/s/bwy4elhvi4qldbd/Whats_New.zip

Please run WhatsNew.html

Comment: Dropbox?? Seriously? :D

Comment: Just wanted to share my code. I am new to the forum. Is there a better way to share my code as I do not have a public URL that I can send to you to see my code. Please advise.

Comment: Do you have the option autoScrollingMode set to endlessLoopRight or endlessLoopLeft?